# Complete gridview returns on Checkbox clicked

Tags: asp.net, gridview, postback

I have a gridview in asp.net and on changing checkbox value, complete gridview returns in response.The data in gridview is very huge and is causing serious performance issues because all data comes in response on checkchange event of checkbox. Please note that postback is compulsory as some operation are working by checking state of checkbox. Here is the code of gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="ObjList" runat="server" OnLoad="ReloadGrid" CssClass="ObjList"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="ObjList_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateSelectButton="false"
    AllowPaging="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="&nbsp" ItemStyle-Width="46px" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox AutoPostBack="true" ID="chkAll" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="HeaderChk_Changed" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="LinkNumIndexHead" runat="server" Value="-1" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox AutoPostBack="true" ID="chkRow" runat="server" Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Selection")%>'
                    OnCheckedChanged="ChkRow_OnCheckChange" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="LinkNumIndex" runat="server" Value="-1" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="46px" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

If i comment the code inside the checkchange event then same results. The screen shot is attached showing data size in single request of checkbox chage event.[image]

Comment: please edit your question and add code C# or whatever where it showing checkbox checkchange event and gridview databind event.

Comment: This data size is creating performance issues on client side.